# Detecting the content in a text box in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have a textbox and I need a script to detect when a user types a link using space as a delimiter. I know how to *detect* links with regex, but I don't know how to effectively check for links (think of Facebook's status updates; type a link, hit space, and it looks that link up). Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery its done like this:

```
$('#someElement').keyUp(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 32){
      //Regex goes here
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user hits a spacebar, grab the content of the textbox, search for the link using regex and surround the link with an  tag...

```
document.getElementById('myTextArea').onkeyup( function () {
    if(event.keycode == 49) { //This is the keycode for spacebar
        var text = document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerText;
        //Perform regex on 'text'
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds simple enough:

```
$('#myTextBox').keyup(function()
{
    var links = $(this).val().split(' ');

    $(links).each(function()
    {
         // If Regex(this) matches link pattern, look up link
    });
});
```